# Data Source creation using ejb.The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, ejb, jndi

```
package myJsp;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.naming.*;

public class A implements SessionBean {   
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
  public void ejbCreate() throws CreateException {    
    ctx = new InitialContext();
    ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/fastCoffeeDB");
  }   
  public void ejbActivate() {
  }
  public void ejbPassivate() {
  }
  public void ejbRemove() {
  }
  public void setSessionContext(SessionContext ctx) {
  }  
  public void updatePrice(float price, String cofName,
                          String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pstmt;
    try {
        con = ds.getConnection(username, password);
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("connection successful");
        con.commit();

    } finally {
        if (con != null) con.close();
    }
  }

  private DataSource ds = null;
  private Context ctx = null;
}
```

I have added javaee.jar file and trying to create jndi interface for my project.

```
  ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/fastCoffeeDB"); 
  ------The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Please edit, showing how you invoke the compiler. Also, did you set environment CLASSPATH, and how?

Comment: Actually I am writing the code in eclipse.and eclipse ide showing the error . I have not invoked and didn't set any class path .

Comment: Did you try menu Project -> Clean..., then rebuild? Also, check Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path ->  Libraries: see "JRE Sys Lib [jdk...]"?

Comment: And the library is there? Can you `import java.lang.CharSequence;` (e.g. in class A) without getting an error?

Comment: The java.lang.CharSequence class was added to Java in version 1.4.  Is it possible you have a version of Java older than 1.4 on your machine?

Comment: I have tried to import java.lang.CharSequence; but It is showing error.

Comment: I am using jdk1.8.0_05.